# Batch file that launch admin login window with Menu Options, unable to open urls on Chrome/MS Edge

Tags: google-chrome, batch, batch-file, url, microsoft-edge

I tried a batch file menu options with a prompt to enter admin password after clicking the bat file icon. But I noticed on the Menu options where it should open multiple websites on chrome, it was not working. I tried to change to MS Edge but it seems to detect only the first 2 websites that I included in the list.

I think it's because I'm running on admin and it somehow launch Chrome as admin too and messed it up as if I run the bat file without the upper part of the script that launches the admin login window it works fine for the websites. Is there a way I can launch Chrome as non-admin account which I can just add on my script?

Below is an example of what I did.

The upper part of my script for the admin window is below: (I use below admin prompt command because I noticed it can't read the text image I saved as .txt file, if I right click Run as Admin- can someone also help to explain why?

```
::::::::::::: Automatically check & get admin rights V2 ::::::::::::

@echo off
 
Color A
 
CLS 

ECHO.
 
ECHO 

====== You're Running Admin Mode! ======
 
:init
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "batchPath=%~0"
for %%k in (%0) do set batchName=%%~nk
set "vbsGetPrivileges=%temp%\OEgetPriv_%batchName%.vbs" 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:checkPrivileges
NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL 
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ( goto gotPrivileges ) else ( goto getPrivileges )

:getPrivileges 
if '%1'=='ELEV' (echo ELEV & shift /1 & goto gotPrivileges) 
ECHO. 
ECHO
*** Invoking UAC for Privilege Escalation *****
ECHO Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%vbsGetPrivileges%" ECHO args = "ELEV " >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%" 
ECHO For Each strArg in WScript.Arguments >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%" 
ECHO args = args ^& strArg ^& " " >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%" 
ECHO Next >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%" 
ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "!batchPath!", args, "", "runas", 1 >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%" 
"%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%vbsGetPrivileges%" %* 
exit /B

:gotPrivileges 
setlocal & pushd 
cd /d %~dp0 
if '%1'=='ELEV' (del "%vbsGetPrivileges%" 1>nul 2>nul & shift /1)

#And below is a part of the Menu options where it launches the websites:

:Launch Daily Websites on Chrome
start chrome https://www.bluematrix.com/www3/CreatorLogin.action 
start chrome https://www.citrix.com/ 
start chrome http://creditmatch.gfigroup.com/asia
ECHO. 
PAUSE
GOTO MAIN MENU
CLS
```

Comment: The part with the `start` commands works fine in Chrome, run elevated or not.

Comment: @harrymc I tried to run again on a different vdi, same issue. What I am getting on Chrome is it is showing "Untitled" tab  with a white empty chrome webpage. (It only happens when I clicked the option where it runs the websites and when I Run as Admin- right click to Chrome) I tried the solution here https://www.guidingtech.com/best-ways-to-fix-google-chrome-untitled-blank-page/ and https://techsmagic.com/how-to-fix-google-chrome-crashing-untitled-in-windows-10 but same issue.

Comment: I get the tabs of: xenstorehk, BlueMatrix, GFI. But I'm doing it from a normal CMD, not from your script.

Comment: For clarity, please [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1708442/edit) your post with any additional information.

Comment: @harrymc any command I can add to run chrome as regular account for below part? I also tried running the below command with normal CMD and no issues. Only on admin account has issue. So I guess the best way is to run chrome as none admin for that part. Thanks

Comment: I repeat: There is no problem with running your `start` commands from an elevated CMD. Your problem must come from the rest of your script.

Comment: @harrymc thanks, I'll check the whole script again.